# How to change from inline CSS to external?

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to css, html and asp.net. I'm trying to clone a website in order to learn web tech concepts. Well, when i write everything in inline css, everything works fine. But when put these inline css codes into an external file, it's all messed up. How can i fix this? I always face this trouble when I use external css. Some of my previous codes are affecting my following or later codes and I face this trouble.

I don't understand how css works. I use classes with dots, ids with # but can't uderstand yet how to put them in an order between my html codes.

I want to add a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agLmnzr3/) When I hover on recipes there's a new div pops up. There are 3 new divs in that popped up div. The 1st div has a list holding the info of soup, legume etc. I want those 3 divs stay next to each other. I want to be able to style them. I don't know how to style nested elements by using class and id. This leads to trouble. To clarify nested elements have a look at this please:
div
paragraph
div
list
a
how to style these elements from an external CSS file instead of inline CSS such as style="bla bla bla"

here's my codes and pics.

```css
.auto-style1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.aMain {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: #ddd6d6;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 13.5px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 180px;
}

.divLogin {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  height: 46px;
  width: 120px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 180px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.pIcon {
  background-color: transparent;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

.pLoginText {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 6px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.divSendRecipe {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 46px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 12px;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: #ff6a00;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.pSendRecipe {
  background-color: transparent;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

.divSearch {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 426px;
  height: 46px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.divSearch .divSearchContainer {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 426px;
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

.divSearch:hover .divSearchContainer {
  display: block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.divSearch .divSearchContainer span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.divSearch .divSearchContainer a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ddd6d6;
  width: 80px;
  height: 24px;
  padding: 3px 0 0 0;
  margin: 4px 0 0 8px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.divSearch input[type=search] {
  all: unset;
  font: 16px system-ui;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 360px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  float: left;
}

.divSearch button {
  all: unset;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 46px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  background-color: #d91616;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.divSearch button:hover {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 500px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.table a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.table td {
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.table td .divContainer {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 732px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 52px;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}


/*.table td .divContainer div {
                    border-style: solid;
                    border-width: 1px;
                    width: 240px;
                    height: 300px;
                    background-color: brown;
                    margin-left: 2px;
                    margin-right: 2px;
                    float:left;
                    margin-top: 52px;
                    position: absolute;
                    display: inline;
                }*/


/*.table td .divContainer ul li a {
                    display: inline-block;
                    background-color: #ddd6d6;
                    width: 244px;
                    height: 24px;
                    padding: 3px 0 0 0;
                    margin: 4px 0 0 8px;
                    border-radius: 25px;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: blue;
                    text-align: left;
                    font-size: 16px;
                }*/

.table td:hover .divContainer {
  background-color: #b50c0c;
  display: block;
}

.image {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  left: 42px;
}
```

```html
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
  <link href="testCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fontAwesome/css/all.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="height: 30px; background-color: #ddd6d6">
      <a href="mainPage.aspx" class="aMain"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>MAIN PAGE</a>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 70px; background-color: #ffffff">
      <a href="mainPage.aspx">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="45px" Width="120px" ImageUrl="pics/logo.png" title="Logo" Style="margin-left: 180px; margin-top: 12px; float: left;" />
      </a>
      <div class="divLogin">
        <p class="pLoginText">
          <strong>Log In<br />
                            or Sign Up</strong>
        </p>
        <p class="pIcon"><i class="fas fa-2x fa-user-circle"></i></p>
      </div>
      <div class="divSendRecipe">
        <p style="margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 15px; text-align: center; float: right; font-size: 15px;"><strong>Send Recipe</strong></p>
        <p class="pIcon"><i class="fas fa-2x fa-marker"></i></p>
      </div>
      <div class="divSearch">
        <input type="search" id="query" name="q" placeholder="Search cook or recipe..." />
        <button><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
        <div class="divSearchContainer">
          <div>
            <span>Popular Searchs</span><br />
            <a href="#">cake</a>
            <a href="#">cookie</a>
            <a href="#">pasta</a>
            <a href="#">dessert</a>
            <a href="#">wet cake</a>
            <a href="#">browni</a>
            <a href="#">pastry</a>
          </div>
          <div><span>My Last Searchs</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="z-index: -1; height: 70px; background-color: #d91616;">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td class="td"><a href="recipesPage.aspx">RECIPES<img class="image" src="pics/cook book.png" /></a>
            <div class="divContainer">
              <div style="width: 240px;height: 300px;background-color: brown; margin-left: 2px; margin-right:2px; margin-top:6px; float:left;">
                <ul>
                  <li style="text-align:left;"><a style="width:230px;height:30px;">Soaps</a></li>
                  <li style="text-align:left;"><a style="width:230px;height:30px;">Legume Recipes</a></li>
                  <li style="text-align:left;"><a style="width:230px;height:30px;">Vegetable Dishes</a></li>
                  <li style="text-align:left;"><a style="width:230px;height:30px;">Meat Dishes</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div style="width: 240px;height: 300px;background-color: brown; margin-left: 2px; margin-right:2px; margin-top:6px; float:left;">div2</div>
              <div style="width: 240px;height: 300px;background-color: brown; margin-left: 2px; margin-right:2px; margin-top:6px;  float:left;">div3</div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="td"><a href="videosPage.aspx">VIDEOS<img class="image" src="pics/camera.png" /></a>
            <div class="divContainer" style="margin-left:-124px;">videos</div>
          </td>
          <td class="td"><a href="trendsPage.aspx">TRENDS<img class="image" src="pics/trends.png" /></a></td>
          <td class="td"><a href="suggestionsPage.aspx">SUGGESTIONS?<img class="image" src="pics/what should i cook.png" /></a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 1000px; height: 1000px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color: #D9FFFF">
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
      </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

this is what my codes do:
[image]

this is what i want it to do:
[image]

this is how my website looks.
[image]

Comment: If you put the CSS in an external .css file then you need to tell your page about the existence of it using a `<link>` tag. You haven't shown one in your sample, so it's not clear if you've done that or not. See https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-get-started.php for details.

Comment: As you are looking for a source to understand the concepts as well, this might help you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS

Comment: P.S. the HTML you've shown doesn't reflect all the contents of your screenshot, so we can't even tell if the CSS would actually work (once included correctly)

Comment: @ADyson oh sorry, i didn't put that part here, already added it to my page. my troubles are generally caused by some other css codes affect my codes. i couldn't handle with this.

Comment: Ok, so please edit your question to show a) the CSS link, and b) a more complete example of the HTML, to reflect the screenshot.

Comment: `my troubles are generally caused by some other css codes affect my codes`...that wasn't your original question. Also if you have "other" CSS code, we need to see that as well before we could tell you where there is any conflict.

Comment: @ADyson i added all of my codes sir. i was summarizing with that sentence why i have that trouble. to simplify my question i guess i should ask this one: my previous css codes affects my current css codes. how can i fix this?

Comment: That can't be all your code. In your screenshot, you divs, and a list containing "soaps", "legume recipes" etc. That seems to be the part where you say there's a problem with the layout. Yet that is the only part you haven't shown any HTML for.

Comment: P.S. The previous editor corrected all your grammar, including capitalising words at the start of sentences properly, which makes the text much more readable. Why did you reverse all of that? English is not written entirely in lower-case.

Comment: Thanks for the update but now it's doubly confusing. We now have two pictures of what your code does (the 1st picture and the 3rd picture), which are different to each other. Which one is the real picture of what it does? And we _still_ can't see the code which is supposed to generate the list you say you want.

Comment: @ADyson :D sorry, I'll do my best to explain what is happening. The 3rd pic is how my website looks. I used a table which has recipes, videos etc. This table is in a div(z index -1, height 70) When you hover on RECIPE(it's a td of table), a new div shows up. I wrote its code in CSS and its class is divContainer. This shown up div has 3 divs in it.  The 1st div has soaps, legume etc. The other divs are div2 and div3. I want these 3 divs to be placed next to each other as I showed in the 2nd pic("This is what I want it to do"). But my codes do the 1st pic, they're one under other.Keep on reading

Comment: @ADyson If I put my CSS codes between the <div style=""> or as inline CSS. It does what I want which is shown in the 2nd pic. But I want to achieve the 2nd pic by putting my codes into an external CSS which is named testCSS.css. But when I put them in external CSS file things shown in the 1st pic happens. I hope this time I could explain it properly. Do you understand what I mean sir?

Comment: Oh I see sorry, those divs are within the same table which defines the heading...That's a _really_ weird markup style. And very retro - people stopped using tables for layout purposes nearly 20 years ago, partly because of better browser support for other types of layout, and partly because it's very verbose, and extremely fiddly to get right, and then very hard to maintain afterwards (requiring lots of detailed alterations to make one small change). It's also not very [semantic](https://html.com/semantic-markup/) - tables are supposed to be for tabular data, not general content or menus.

Comment: I suggest taking some time to learn about modern grid layouts, or flexbox, instead. These will produce much better results (as well as being more responsive on different screen sizes, easier to test, easier to maintain and adapt etc)

Comment: P.S. Simply putting the CSS into a different file doesn't fundamentally change the way it works. Perhaps something in the other CSS file (style.css) conflicts with it. Since you've put style.css second, anything in style.css which affects the same elements and rules will take precedence over what's in testcss.css. But I don't think you've shown us what's in that other file. BTW you can use your browser's element inspector to see what rules are being applied to each element, and where the rule came from.

Comment: @ADyson Sir, I said I'm a very new to CSS :D. I've been studying it for a week. I don't study or don't have a mentor, I'm just enthusiastic. I don't know what to study, what to search or how to explain problems :( Sorry for that. Well, I'll search about what you mentioned.

Comment: @ADyson By the way, I have a new problem. When I define a div's style as inline such as <div style="z-index: -1; height: 70px; background-color: #d91616;"> it works properly. But when I put these codes into my testCSS file the background color of the div doesn't change. How can I fix this? I think this problem and the previous one are caused by the same root/basis. I don't know how to style an element from an external CSS file, if I learn this properly, it would be easier to handle the rest of the CSS. Do you have any suggestions about learning the basics of or nesting the elements?

Comment: `I don't know what to study, what to search`...that's fine, I wasn't being critical of you personally, just pointing out that you might want to learn about something up to date instead. So now you have a better idea what to search and learn about :-)

Comment: @ADyson Sir, when you said there's a style.css file, I realized that I don't have a file like it. I only use testCSS. Should I delete it?

Comment: If no such file exists then yes you can delete the link to it

Comment: @ADyson here's a https://jsfiddle.net/agLmnzr3/ and I edited my question about nested elements.  Maybe you want to havea look at them. I think if I properly get defining nested elements from an external file I would be able to solve this issue.

Comment: @ADyson All right thanks for help.  I solved the problem by playing with class attributes. There was something overriding my codes. I need so much practising with classes, IDs and selectors. Though I want to ask one more question as well. When I run my project on Chrome which is already default browser, it seems like, sometimes Chrome doesn't take every info or every line of codes. When I restart my laptop it works well at first. But after a while the same missing thing happens again. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: It's probably caching your page and your CSS. You can force it to reload from the server fully by using ctrl+f5 to fully refresh the page and associated files. Glad you solved the main issue anyway.

Comment: @ADyson okay, thanks. Have a nice day

Answer (score 3):

> when put these inline css codes into an external file, it's all messed up. how can i fix this? i always face this trouble when i use external css.

You can your css in a separate `.css` file and import it to your HTML file inside the `<head></head>` tags.

I think the below example explains it clearly.

Here I have my CSS in a separate `.css` file called `myStyle.css`. Then I have imported it to my HTML file. **Remember in this example, both files are inside the same directory.** Of course, you can put them anywhere and change the `href` accordingly.

```css
/* myStyle.css */

.table {
border-collapse: collapse;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 500px;
height: 70px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link href="myStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

Comment: well, i already recognized my page the css file but didn't share that part here. i'm facing a trouble like this: my codes are somehow affected by other codes. i can't get over it.

Comment: is your code specificity stronger than "other codes"?

Answer (score 2):

## The code share in the question

is not separating your CSS code into another file, but it is putting it inside the file as text, which is not evaluated as CSS. First, try to put that CSS code into a `style` tag as a proof-of-concept:

```
<style type="text/css">
.table {
border-collapse: collapse;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 500px;
height: 70px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.table a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.table td {
    width: 25%;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid;
}

    .table td .divContainer {
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 732px;
        height: 400px;
        margin-top: 52px;
        border-width: 1px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        z-index: 1;
        position: relative;
        display: none;
    }

        .table td .divContainer div {
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            width: 240px;
            height: 300px;
            background-color: brown;
            margin-left: 2px;
            margin-right: 2px;
            margin-top: 52px;
            float:left;
            position: absolute;
            display: inline;
        }

        .table td .divContainer ul li a {
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: #ddd6d6;
            width: 244px;
            height: 24px;
            padding: 3px 0 0 0;
            margin: 4px 0 0 8px;
            border-radius: 25px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: blue;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

    .table td:hover .divContainer {
        background-color: #b50c0c;
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

Once that works, you can proceed in separating the CSS code into a file.

## Linking a CSS file

Let's create a CSS called style.css. Remember where it is and add this code to your `head` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/my/correct/path/style.css">
```

Now, load your page in the browser. Look at the Console of your Dev Tools. If you see an error that states that the file was not successfully loaded, then you have specified the wrong path. Fix the path until loading your page no longer complains about the file not being loaded correctly.

## Moving the CSS

Now copy the inner content of your `style` tag discussed earlier and paste into your style.css. Don't copy the `<style type="text/css">`, nor the `</style`. Remove the `style` tag. Reload the page. Make sure that for now style.css does not contain anything else. Work until the page reflects your styling.

## Resolve conflicts

Now, assuming that you have different external CSS that conflicts with your rule, the first question is: do you need the external CSS? If not, then don't load it. If yes, then adjust your rules to be more specific than the remote CSS's rules if you want your CSS to be reflected. Change your structure if necessary. Work on your structure and design bit-by-bit until you fix all conflicting rules and your page looks good.

## Test in several browsers

When you are done with your changes, load your page in several browsers and see whether some browsers don't handle your design well. If so, find out what the problems are and fix them.

Comment: i added whole of my codes, sir. css codes of other parts are in the same file as my table codes. previous parts are working well. but table part isn't working properly. firstly, i had added only the codes of table part. but now i added all of my codes.some codes in the table area are affecting my innermost div's codes which is the div of divContainer

Comment: @electriciansmurf okay, please create a Fiddle with a problem and explain what the intention was and what you have got instead. Reviewing all of your code would be too time-consuming, so, let's focus on a single issue for now and once we figure out what the problem is and what the solution is, hopefully you will be able to apply the same idea for the other conflicts. If not, then we get to the next problem as well. So, we should solve one well-defined problem at a time.

Comment: okay, I don't know how to create a Fiddle but I'l search about it. So, instead of a Fiddle, I added 2 pics of what I want and what my code does.

Comment: @electriciansmurf I have seen them, but in order to convert the behavior from one picture into another, one would have to fix all problems. That might require some hard labor. My point is that we should take a single problem and fix that first. Maybe if we do that, then you will be able to fix the other problems. If fixing a problem still leaves you with questions, then we can fix the second problem and so on. So, let's focus on Minimal, Reproducible examples. As about creating a fiddle, visit https://jsfiddle.net/, add your problem there, save and share the link.

Comment: @electriciansmurf but, again, people here will be less willing to fix all your problems than fixing a single problem at a time.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/agLmnzr3/ thank you I learnt a new thing from you.I hope we can solve this problem. By th way when I define a div's style as inline such as <div style="z-index: -1; height: 70px; background-color: #d91616;"> it works properly. But when I put these codes into my testCSS file the background color of the div doesn't change. How can I fix this? I don't know how to style an element from an external CSS file, if I learn this properly, it would be easier to handle the rest of the CSS. I don't know how to use class and id properly.

Comment: @electriciansmurf your fiddle illustrates your design when things are defined inline. Can you also create another Fiddle where the content of your CSS files are embedded into a `style` tag? If that Fiddle would work well, then your problem is how they are linked into your page. If the Fiddle would not work well, then your problem is with the rules.

Comment: @electriciansmurf the idea is to have a tiny-miny example where the problem is always reliably reproduced and is obvious for us, who want to help you. At this point I'm not sure whether the problem is with conflicting rules that you may have, or the problem is incorrect linking of CSS files. I suspect that you have some conflicting rules. You could create a Fiddle where you paste all your CSS from the file into the CSS section and the HTML (without the inline rules) into the structure section.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved the problem that night. The problem was caused by overriding on hovering and some class & id attributes.

Comment: @electriciansmurf so the problem was that some rules were conflicting. Think about it: if you had searched for a conflict between CSS rules, like I have suggested, then you have surely located at least a problem. By locating the problem you have half of the solution. So, if you try to provide details for the question you ask, then you might find the solution during that.

Comment: Thanks you're right. You know I'm new around here and in programming so I'm learning gradually :)

Comment: @electriciansmurf no worries. When I was learning how to program, there were no such forums and I had to figure all these out by myself. It's nice that people have an easier time nowadays.